# Proof using sets and infinimums

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Let $S$ and $T$ be nonempty sets of real numbers, bounded below. Prove that $$\inf(S\cup T) = \min \{\inf S,\inf T \} $$

So the answer almost seems obvious here, I get that obviously the inf of the union of the two sets is the smaller of the two infs from both sets. It's just, proving this obvious statement.

I attempt it as follows: The union of S and T covers all elements in S and T, thus elements in S do not necessarily have to be in T and vice versa. Every finite nonempty subset of real numbers has a max and min, but infinite non empty subsets don't have a min, but an inf.

So let the union of S and T be a subset of real numbers. If $m\leq s$ for all $s\in S\cup T$ then m is lower bound for S and $S\cup T$ is bounded below.

Since it is bounded below there must be an inf according to some definition that states "If S is bounded below and S has a greatest lower bound, then
we will call it the infimum of S and denote it by inf S."

Thus $\inf(S\cup T) = \min\{\inf S,\inf T\}$.

But I don't think is the appropriate way to approach this question.

Comment: For future reference, \min and \inf (as well as \max and \sup) are acceptable $\LaTeX$ commands.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, latex just has an obscene amount of commands it feels impossible to remember them all

Comment: You get used to it after a while. Worst case scenario is just to try something and see if it works. Often $\LaTeX$ commands are WYTIWYG (What You Think Is What You Get).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

You need to show two things:

1. $\min\{\inf S,\inf T\}$ is a lower bound on $S\cup T$.
2. Any lower bound $m$ on $S\cup T$ satisfies $m\leq\min\{\inf S,\inf T\}$.

The former is almost immediate, since $\min\{\inf S,\inf T\}\leq\inf S$ and $\min\{\inf S,\inf T\}\leq\inf T$.  For the latter, consider trying a proof by contradiction: suppose you have a lower bound $m$ which is bigger than $\min\{\inf S,\inf T\}$.

Comment: Would the latter be as simple as stating that,$\min(S\cup T) =inf(S\cup T)$ thus $m$ cannot be greater than $\min(S\cup T)$?

Comment: @Iam126264. No, because there's no reason to assume that $\min(S\cup T)$ exists.

Comment: @Iam126264. Think about it this way: if $m>\min\{\inf S,\inf T\}$, then necessarily either $m>\inf S$ or $m>\inf T$.  If $m>\inf S$, then can $m$ possibly be a lower bound on $S\cup T$?

Comment: That was the actually the same logic I was going down and was hoping it was correct. The definition of a lower bound states that there exists some $m$ such that $m\leq s \forall s\in S$. So by that definition and the above reasoning you suggested, m cannot be a lower bound. But is that a satisfactory enough answer?

Comment: @Iam126264. If you include all of the details, yes.  Make sure that you have explicitly shown both (1) and (2).  Expand on the outline of the argument of (2) that I gave you to explicitly show why that is a contradiction.

Comment: Ok, sounds good, thanks a lot. I have the gist of it, I included a subset S of ${R}$ for the definition of the lower bound showing m cannot be a lower bound if its greater than $\forall s \in S$